# target=_blank to open a tab, and if failing opening a tab, opens popup with height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, popup

Currently, when you give a `a` tag a `target="_blank"` property, Chrome, Firefox, and modern IE browsers will open the link in a new tab. Safari and older IE will open it in a new tab. Using `window.open` is consistent in opening a popup for all browsers and lets you specify `height` and `width`, but modern browsers have popup blockers that will block it. Opening a new tab with `target="blank"` is fine/preferred, but for the browsers that are going to open that in a popup, I'd like to specify `height` and `width`, as the popup that older IE is opening is very small.

**Is there a way (besides browser detection) to open a new tab, and failing that, open a new popup with a specified height and width?** I believe that there is a way to do this in the reverse order, but I'd rather have the user not see a "popup blocked" alert, and then a new tab appear.

And, yes, I know that popups are annoying and insulting and terrible. This is something being asked of me by another.

Comment: User's settings determine whether a window is opened in a new tab vs a new window.  Not much you can do to determine the behavior.  You can always make it a popup by specifying additional arguments, that way you'll get consistency.  I believe most browsers will not block a popup if it's a single popup that is triggered from a user click.

Answer (score 0):

The window.open method, will work when it is associated with a click event. Is this window.open associated with a click event?

** EDIT **
I have also found that a popup (window.open) tends to get hidden accidentally by users. If possible use a modal box method (like jQuery's lightbox, thickbox, simple modal, etc).